# How to get TextField Input and why the input repeat when I scroll?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, textfield

I create TableViewCells like this:

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ErnaehrungTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! ErnaehrungTableViewCell
    let row = indexPath.row
    cell.LabelType.text = cellValues[indexPath.row]
    cell.TextValue.keyboardType = .decimalPad
    cell.TextValue.tag = indexPath.row

    cell.selectionStyle = .none
    cell.ButtonUnit.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ErnaehrungManualController.ButtonUnitClick), for: .touchUpInside)
    cell.ButtonUnit.tag = indexPath.row`
```

LabelType ist a Label, TextValue a Textfield and ButtonUnit is a Button.
It looks like this:
[image]

If I type in at the first five TextFields (as shown) and I scroll, the inputs are in other rows, too.

How can I fix that?

If I press the Button at the upper right (Fertig) then I want to read the text of all TextFields. I have this code, but I doesn't work:

```
for var i in 0...cellValues.count-1 {
        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: i, section: 0)
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ErnaehrungTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! ErnaehrungTableViewCell

        if let text = cell.TextValue.text, !text.isEmpty
        {
            let textString = cell.TextValue.text!
            print(textString)

        }
    }
```

So how can I fix that the TextFields (where I not typed in a text) don't copy the input of other TextFields?

And how I can read out the TextField.text for all rows?

Thanks for help, if you need more code, I will add that.

Comment: you have written complex logic , here actual problem is not in your code, it the basic functionality how  dequeueReusableCell will work,  it just replicates old cell to form new cell. Please read about that first, and try writing code for small inputs, will really help you in resolve your problem.

Comment: and how can I fix it? Or how I could do it better?

Comment: I am just going thrw ur code, will get back with some suggestion soon..

Comment: I think, which i used previously, use array to store whatever you are write in textfields, and use that array to get values out of table, your using for loop and cells to get values, use array to store input to textfields and same to outputs.

Comment: I should write the data in an array and delete that out of the TextField? But the I can't see the input at the TextField right?

Comment: Probably you should read about reusing tableViewCells. Another thing you must do is to store the input entered by the user and use that input when you return the cell in cellForRow method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because of dequeue the cell which reuses the cell . In order to avoid this issue, store the value in an array and then set the value when table view delegate is called. In SWIFT 3

```
var dataList = ["","","",""] // Array size should be same as the total row count


func textFieldShouldEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool { 

    if textField.text != ""{

        dataList[textField.tag] = textField.text!
    }
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ErnaehrungTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! ErnaehrungTableViewCell
    let row = indexPath.row
    cell.LabelType.text = cellValues[indexPath.row]
    cell.TextValue.text = dataList[indexPath.row] // Setting the value here
    cell.TextValue.keyboardType = .decimalPad
    cell.TextValue.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.TextValue.delegate = self // Setting delegate here
    cell.selectionStyle = .none
    cell.ButtonUnit.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ErnaehrungManualController.ButtonUnitClick), for: .touchUpInside)
    cell.ButtonUnit.tag = indexPath.row`

}
```

Comment: I try it, give me a moment

Comment: Welcome buddy :-)